# Tour to Fukushima closed area?

Tags: japan, tours, extreme-tourism

There are several travel agent in Ukraine which organise Chernobyl tour and visited the Closed Area.

Is there any travel agents in Japan organising similar trips to Fukushima Closed Area?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Officially or even semi officially no.  The plant is still owned by TEPCO so arranging it with them would probably give you a better access and safer tour if they choose to allow it.

However, there are other options if you choose to consider them.

There is a [boat tour that approaches the plant from sea](https://www.govoyagin.com/activities/see-fukushima-daiichi-power-plant-with-your-own-eyes/3365) or a [Fairewinds](http://www.fairewinds.org/) virtual tour.  Or finally you can try to get a [local to give you a tour](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-2860422/Japan-s-latest-tourist-attraction-Locals-offer-sightseeing-trips-Fukushima-amid-claims-contamination-levels-low-whistle-stop-visit.html) of the area but there are no contacts given so you may want to consider the repercussions of doing so and what kind of access you will be able to get remains a mystery.

Comment: and remember that entering the plant area without permission from TEPCO will be tresspassing. I'm not sure about Japan, but entering an area where nuclear materials are stored or worked with here without proper permits and equipment can get you in serious trouble here and in most countries.

Comment: Isn't the exclusion area bigger than the plant itself? Or did they reduce the area?

Comment: It is bigger, but don't think they control 2 perimeters with guards on the inner perimeter too. There will be a fence but nothing more I guess